# Join two tables who both have a record

Tags: sql, join

I need to join two tables with a shared ID, but I only want to return a row if both tables contain a row.  I found a solution with sub-queries, but want to avoid them (because this query is run multiple times a page load).

An example:

```
`Products`:
Name    PicID
------|-------
Test1 |   4
Test2 |   5


`Images`:
PicID   Picture
------|--------
   4  |  BLOB
```

A query would only return Test1 (with the blob) because Test2 doesn't have a row in the picture table.

Thoughts?
Max

Comment: You should probably explain why a standard `JOIN` doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` is used to guarantee that the matching values exist in both tables.

```
SELECT p.PicID, p.Name, i.Picture
    FROM Products p
        INNER JOIN Images i
            ON p.PicID = i.PicID
```

Comment: wow, can't believe I forgot that.  I kept thinking inner join was if it was in either table.  Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT P.Name, P.PicID, I.Picture
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Images I
ON p.PicID = I.PicID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
FROM Products, Images
WHERE Product.PicID = Images.PicID
```